# How to input endlessly by shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to use shell script to generate data to my Kafka topic.

Firstly, I write a shell script `run_producer.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic AAATest2 \
  --property "parse.key=true" \
  --property "key.separator=:" \
  --property key.schema='{"type":"string"}' \
  --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"measurement","type":"string"},{"name":"id","type":"int"}]}'
```

It requires you to input string like `"key1":{"measurement": "INFO", "id": 1}` in command line when the `run_producer.sh` is executed, and you can input as many as you want.

I write another script `add_data.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

s="\"key1\":{\"measurement\": \"INFO\", \"id\": 1}"
printf "${s}\n${s}\n" | ./run_producer.sh
```

It can input the string 2 times, or more by adding "${s}\n" in `printf`, but it is limited and stupid.

I want to make it inputs the string endlessly until I stop it. How can I do that with shell script ?

I will be very grateful if you can tell me how to make the string differently(different data) by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `yes "$s"` to produce endless input for your script. But what do you meen by "make the string differently"? Will be enough to use infinite loop with some random data, like

```
while true; do s="\"key1\":{\"measurement\": \"INFO\", \"id\": $RANDOM}"; echo $s; done
```

or you need modify it in some other way?

`man bash`:

```
   RANDOM Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between 0 and 32767 is generated.  The sequence of random numbers may  be  initialized by assigning a value to RANDOM.  If RANDOM is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.
```

You could combine it with anything else, like: `"key_${RANDOM}"`
Or choose any other method like https://gist.github.com/earthgecko/3089509 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230673/how-to-generate-a-random-string

Comment: Thanks, you get my thought. Can `$RANDOM` generate random string ? Can it generate different string with the format I want, like `key_xxx`, 'xxx' is a random numbers ?

Comment: @waveschj I added more info to my answer about RANDOM and some links about generating random strings in shell

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with shell script. I try ```flag=1
while true; 
 do s="\"key_${RANDOM}\":{\"measurement\": \"INFO\", \"id\": $RANDOM}";
 if [ $flag -eq 1 ];then
  yes "$s" | ./run_producer.sh
  flag=2
 fi
done```, but the $s is always the same. How should I modify it?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what result you want to achieve. You could try `s="..."; yes "$s" | ./run_producer.sh` to get infinite stream of same messages of "$s". Or you could make `while true; do s="..."; echo "$s" | ./run_producer.sh; done` to get infinite loop of random messages. Or you could use `for i in {1..10}; do s="..."; echo "$s" | ./run_producer.sh; done` to get finite loop of messages. But I don't understand your usage of "flag" variable and what you trying to achieve.

Comment: I want `./run_producer.sh` only run once, and it already can receive endless string.  And each time it receive the $s, the $s should be different. Can you understand me? But I think once run `yes "$s" | ./run_producer.sh` , the $s will always the same string.

Comment: ok. `(while true; do s="\"key_${RANDOM}\": { ... }"; echo "$s"; done) | ./run_producer.sh` -- is what you need if I understand you right.